# Detours 3.0: Hook all exports in a dll

Tags: winapi, detours

I'm currently having issues figuring out what calls an application is making, and was thinking of implementing a way to hook all of the exports inside of a dll, for example `user32.dll`, instead of having to hook them one by one in hopes of hooking the correct export that an application is calling. I would be using this code for debugging purposes so then I can add the exports that are getting called to my main code.

---

I was thinking of implementing this by:

1. Using Visual Studio's `dumpbin` and calling `/EXPORTS` from it to get all of the exports names inside of a dll.
2. Parsing `winuser.h` to find the functions from the export names that I obtained earlier from `Step 1` and then saving their parameters.
3. Hooking every export from `Step 1` with their corresponding parameter from `Step 2`.

---

My question is if this is a good way to go about this, or if this method will work at all?

Comment: Win32 API spy tools already exist, such as [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).

Comment: @RemyLebeau You sir, are a god among men. You have saved me countless hours, if not days, of work.